# Sequelize - Calling Triggers functions using hooks

Tags: node.js, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, sequelize.js

I want to implement soft_delete. So I have created a hook in my model class `beforeBulkDelete` that calls a stored procedure that put some date in `deleted_at` column and returns `TRIGGER`.

I want to return `NULL` as a trigger so actual delete won't happen.

I tried creating triggers using `CREATE TRIGGER` command instead of using Sequelize hooks and it works fine. But I would like to do it using hooks.

Here's my model class -

````
```export default function defineAttachment(
  sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize,
  DataTypes: any
) {
  const XerceCaseAttachment = sequelize.define(
    'XerceCaseAttachment',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      .
      .
      .
      deletedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'deleted_at',
      },
    },
    {
      tableName: 'attachments',
      hooks: {
        beforeBulkDestroy: (options: any) => {
          sequelize.query(`SELECT soft_delete();`, {
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.DELETE,
            transaction: options.transaction,
          });
        },
      },
    }
  );```
````

Here's my `soft_delete` stored procedure -

````
```CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION soft_delete()
 RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
   BEGIN
     RAISE NOTICE 'test triggers';
     EXECUTE 'UPDATE attachments SET deleted_at = current_timestamp WHERE id = $1';
     RETURN NULL;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;```
````

I am getting following error -

````
```Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: trigger functions can only be called as triggers
    at Query.formatError (/home/ishankhanduja/Cyberdyne/cyberdyne/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:363:16)
    at query.catch.err (/home/ishankhanduja/Cyberdyne/cyberdyne/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:86:18)
    at bound (domain.js:395:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:408:12)
    at tryCatcher (/home/ishankhanduja/Cyberdyne/cyberdyne/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/ishankhanduja/Cyberdyne/cyberdyne/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/ishankhanduja/Cyberdyne/cyberdyne/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/ishankhanduja/Cyberdyne/cyberdyne/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/ishankhanduja/Cyberdyne/cyberdyne/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/ishankhanduja/Cyberdyne/cyberdyne/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/home/ishankhanduja/Cyberdyne/cyberdyne/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/ishankhanduja/Cyberdyne/cyberdyne/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/ishankhanduja/Cyberdyne/cyberdyne/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:120:23)```
````

Expectation -

It should not delete the row instead some date get stored in deleted_at

Comment: Use a trigger. That is more efficient and reliable.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for your reply. But is there any specific reason to use triggers instead of hooks? I mean in terms of performance or something?. Because I have been using hooks for creating records and it works fine.

Comment: My reasons are: 1) it is faster and 2) it is reliable (runs in the same transaction). Disclaimer: being a database guy, I trust the database more.